# Escrevendo um arquivo csv no Google Drive usando Colab

Tags: python, google, web-scraping, ipython-notebook

Estou escrevendo um código em Python para raspar informações do Facebook. Gostaria de salvar essas informações em um arquivo no Google Drive, já que estou trabalhando com outras pessoas e usamos o Colaboratory.

**Problema**

O código não escreve o arquivo no Google Colab.

**Código**

```
import facebook_scraper
import pandas as pd
import csv
from facebook_scraper import get_posts

listaBibliotecas = ["bibliotecafoa"]

for biblioteca in listaBibliotecas:
  print("Biblioteca: " + biblioteca) 
for post in get_posts(biblioteca, pages=300):
  post['title'] = biblioteca
  print(post['title'])    
  print(post['post_id'])
  print(post['time'])
  print(post['text'])
  print(post['image'])
  print(post['video'])
  print(post['likes'])
  print(post['comments'])
  print(post['shares'])
  print(post['link'])

  data = [post['title'],post['post_id'], post['time'], post['text'], post['image'], post['video'], post['likes'], post['comments'], post['shares'], post['link']]
  df=pd.DataFrame(data)    
  
  with open("RedesBibliotecas.csv", "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(data)
 
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount ('/drive')
df.to.csv('/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks');
```

**O que eu tentei**

Segui o tutorial do Colab mas não funcionou.
Já montei o drive com o código:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount ('/drive')
df.to.csv('/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks');
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: O que diz a mensagem de erro?

Comment: esse `Colab Notebooks` está escrito assim mesmo. Com espaço? Se sim, tente salvar após a remoção do espaço

Comment: @Lucas oi!! Não tem mensagem de erro, apenas não escreve o arquivo em csv. O programinha roda normal.

Comment: @Lucas Hey, obrigada por responder. É com espaço sim, tanto o My Drive quanto to Google Colab. Ao menos é assim que tá no próprio tutorial do Colab.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao terminal do google colab? Se sim, verifique se é possível transferir os arquivos da sua sessão para o Drive usando o comando `gsutil`. Leai sobre aquui: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil Em último caso, salve o arquivo no Google Storage e de lá envie para o Drive

Comment: Oi, Lucas! Obriada pela opção de leitura. Chequei a conexão e não tem nada de errado, o problema é no código, acho.

Comment: Clara, possivelmetne vocẽ não tenha muita failiaridade com programação - ao responder percebi alguns detalhes do tipo trocar "_" por ".", etc -- -um programa de computador _não_ vai funcionar se trocarmos coisas desse tipo -os nomes e a sintaxe não tem ambiguidade ou espaço para escrever as coisas "um pouquinho diferente" - o legal pode ser interagir com Python no modo interativo, com pequenos exemplos, por exemplo, criar uma lista, inserir um elemento, endereçar um elemento na lista.Você pode usar o colab mesmo pra isso, em uma célula com poucas linahs de código - d 1 a 5  e mandando executar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chamada ao "mount" faz o google drive ficar disponível para o programa em Python como se estivesse na pasta "/drive"  (em Unix, ao contrário de Windows, diretórios não tem uma letra de drive antes - o "/" indica a raiz do sistema de arquivos, como se fosse "C:" em um Windows com uma única partição).

Aí, o conteúdo do seu google-drive está na pasta `/drive/MyDrive`  (**sem espaço** entre "My" e "Drive").

O que significa que qualquer arquivo que você criar a partir da pasta `/drive/MyDrive/` com o Python fica persistido no seu google-drive, e funciona como um arquivo normal em Python. O terceiro componente do caminho "Colab Notebooks" já seria uma pasta dentro do seu drive.

Então, se você colocou " " entre "My" e "Drive" e não deu erro, pode ser que o arquivo tenha ido parar em algum "limbo" no seu google-drive, que não pode ser acessado normalmente por que não está dentro do "MyDrive".

E, do jeito que você escreveu, de qualquer forma, o arquivo "csv" em si vai ficar com o nome "Colab Notebooks"  (sem a extensão ".csv"  - quando você cria um arquivo por meio de um programa de computador tem sempre que incluir a extensão> programas específicos como "word" ou "excel" sabem completar a extensão deles (docx, xlsx), mas justamente por que isso está programado neles).

Ainda há um outro erro no seu programa, que faria com que ele não pudesse rodar, mesmo que o resto funcione - o método do DataFrame para criar um arquivo CSV é `to_csv`, e não `to.csv`. Isso sozinho daria um erro, então estou estranhando então a sua informação de que  "O programinha roda normal" como você escreveu no comentário - você esta realemente executando a célula com esse código apertando "shift + enter" (ou pelos menus `Runtime/runall` ?)

Resumindo, isso aqui deve funcionar:

```py
...

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount ('/drive')
df.to_csv('/drive/MyDrive/meu_arquivo_csv.csv')
```

A primeira parte do programa também está errada - mesmo que a parte de coletar os dados do facbok esteja correta, e as impressões aparecendo, você está mandando o pyhton gravar dados direto, sem passar pelo Pandas, no arquivo "RedeBibliotecas.csv" - até aí tudo bem (esse arquivo deve ser visível pelo próprio script Python, dentro do ambiente do colab) - mas você cria um novo dataframe `data` para cada registro processado - o que vai chegar na hra de gravar o dataframe na última parte do programa é só o último registro.

Comment: Olá, @jsbueno! Primeiro, obrigada pela aula, isso já valeu a coragem de escrever aqui. Foi muto esclarecedor. 

Sim, o programa roda sem erros, ao menos a parte do scraping, mas na gravação, eu não consegui avançar. Consigo escrever o CSV usando o Visual Code e modificando o código para 

 with open("20201202fbcode.csv", "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerow(data)

Comment: Eu estou recebendo um erro de falta de atribuição do dataframe df na última linha do código. 

Da sua resposta, não entendi o seguinte comentário "A primeira parte do programa também está errada - mesmo que a parte de coletar os dados do facbok esteja correta, e as impressões aparecendo, você está mandando o pyhton gravar dados direto, sem passar pelo Pandas, no arquivo "RedeBibliotecas.csv" - até aí tudo bem  - mas você cria um novo dataframe data para cada registro processado - o que vai chegar na hra de gravar o dataframe na última parte do programa é só o último registro."